# Functions work from menu or manually run - but not using Google Time Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have two functions - 
-The first gets Emails - `getEmails();`
-The second deletes my Trash - `deleteForever();`

a) I created a custom menu to trigger the above functions separately & they both function.
b) After testing I added a Google **Project Trigger using Timed Event**

The getEmails Function *stops working **properly***.
When Ran, the script has no errors & the results are:

1. Data insert into worksheet **<- REASON FOR THIS POST-THIS NEVER HAPPENS**
2. Emails move to trash `getEmails();` <- **SUCCESS-I physically See it**
3. Emails delete w/  `deleteForever();` <- **SUCCESS-I physically See it**

Environment Variations: I tested when spreadsheet & gmail was both open and closed in browser

FIX Attempt: I had used getActiveSheet() * Note it Commented it out *
And replaced with the actual spreadsheet ID thinking that would help my problem but same results.

Any ideas?

**Function 1** - (does not work with project trigger timmed event DOES work manually executing)

```
function getEmails() {

   /*var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();*/
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Y-MY-SPREADSHEET-ID-8q9q98k");
    var threads = GmailApp.search("is:starred in:WebOppCRM");
    var row = ss.getLastRow();   

for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {

 /* COMMENT OUT TO FOCUS ON PURPOSE OF QUESTION  
 var start = new Date();
    if (isTimeUp_(start)) {
    Logger.log("Time up");
    break;
  }
  */
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    var newrow = row + 1;

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
        var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
        var dat = messages[j].getDate();
        var msgParse ='=SPLIT($A'+ (newrow) + ', "|")';
        ss.appendRow([msg, dat, msgParse]);
        newrow = newrow +1;
      Utilities.sleep(100);// pause in the loop for 200 milliseconds
    }
    threads[i].moveToTrash();
  }
```

**Function 2** - does work with project triggers or manual

```
function deleteForever() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash");
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("tannerfasteners@gmail.com", threads[i].getId());
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you add your function isTimeUp_(start) also?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking - but whether that function is embedded in there or not the script behaves as I said - it works if I use the custom menu to trigger it, as soon as I add a project trigger time event - only the deleteforever function works as expected

Comment: that `timerisUp()` function - I'm not sure it's even working - it is just supposed to break and stop the process if I exceed the processing time for the google script - otherwise I have to reprocess everything again

Comment: It could also be that you have emptied your sheet, but the appendRow function still counts row 100+ as your last row, check the bottom.

Comment: This I had run into before adding timer, purged fields, data - and have not had this problem again. If I manually run function `getEMails();`  - it flows right through perfectly

Comment: It does work here with the trigger as well. Note that threads[i].moveToTrash() will remove it every time. I would comment that out testing it.

Comment: It would have worked if OPENED to the sheet pulling data. However it couldn't have with the sheets all closed without specifying the focus sheet as I posted in my answer @Wim den Herder - I appreciate the help but the original responses were not relevant to my actual question and the solution did not solve my issue. I detailed my answer out - I wish I could have accepted yours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really would rather accept an answer by another, however nothing above even addressed my problem as to what I specifically laid out.

**The answer was to give focus to the specific sheet when it was not opened by me.**

I Realized

1. code was executing at the top of the script
2. code and functions below were executing
3. The script has not instructed WHAT Sheet to use

Kind of obvious now too - when moving from

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

to the following and having the sheet closed

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-My-Sheet-ID-Removed-");
```

There was no way the data could write without knowing what sheet to write to.

Modifying my script and adding the line marked as /*SOLUTION>*/ below worked to set an active sheet

```
              var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-My-ID-Here"); 
/*SOLUTION>*/  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('data'))
              var threads = GmailApp.search("is:starred in:WebOppCRM");
              var row = ss.getLastRow();
```

This resolved my specific problem and question as to why it worked when the sheet was open ( because the sheet was active by my being on it ) but partially stopped when sheet was closed ( because the sheet was obviously no longer active )

Hopefully this saves someone some debug time.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this function. It's working here, also with a time driven trigger.

```
function isTimeUp_(start) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - start.getTime() > 300000; // alert above 3 minutes, to keep it under 5 minutes
}
```

Comment: This may very well be true and you may have stumbled across another issue - so to keep relevant - I think I should comment this out. I adjusted my post so you can see which part of the script does not happen. I appreciate the effort!